# C# - Locking a resource when obtained from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, multithreading, locking

I have a Dictionary that tracks objects (ClientObject). Both the dictionary and ClientObject's are accessed by multiple threads. When I modify or read any object in this dictionary, I obtain a read or write lock on the dictionary using ReaderWriterLockSlim (rwl_clients) then obtain an exclusive lock on the actual object.

I just wanted to know if I am using these .net threading facilities correctly

Example:

```
rwl_clients.EnterReadLock();
ClientObject clobj;
if(!m_clients.TryGetValue(key, out clobj))
    return;
rwl_clients.ExitReadLock();

SomeMethod(clobj);
```

SomeMethod(ClientObject clobj) would do something like:

```
lock(clobj) {

/// Read / Write operations on clobj

}
```

Does getting and locking a value (ClientObject) from the dictionary in one thread mean that other threads will respect that lock? In other words, does .net see a value in the dictionary as a single resource (and not a copy) and will therefore respect a lock on that resource in all threads?

One more question, when removing a resource from the dictionary - should I lock it before performing Remove()

Example:

```
rwl_clients.EnterWriteLock();
ClientObject clobj;
if(m_clients.TryGetValue(key, out clobj)) {
     lock(clobj) {
          m_clients.Remove(key);
     }
}
rwl_clients.ExitWriteLock();
```

I have learned so much from this site and appreciate any responses!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does getting and locking a value (ClientObject) from the dictionary in one thread mean that other threads will respect that lock? In other words, does .net see a value in the dictionary as a single resource (and not a copy) and will therefore respect a lock on that resource in all threads?

It depends on the type - if a reference type then yes, if a value type no.  This is also why you should never, ever lock on a value type since the value type will be boxed and any subsequent attempts to lock on that value will actually acquire a lock on a different object.

> One more question, when removing a resource from the dictionary - should I lock it before performing Remove()

Yes, you should lock before any operation that mutates the state of the object.

As a side note - are you sure that this setup is the best possible solution to your problem?  Mutable objects shared across threads tend to create more problems then they solve.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This really cleared things up for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding or removing items from the dictionary, lock the dictionary.

When you put an object in the dictionary, you are putting a REFERENCE to that object in the dictionary.   To prevent that object from being changed by a second thread while the first thread is in the process of changing it, lock the object, not the dictionary.

Comment: Only if it is a reference type - the OP's approach will not work for value types.

Comment: I should be fine if my dictionary is locked with ReaderWriterLockSlim and the items are reference type